# how do show data on select option when select ng-click="show({xm.id})" using angular js

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs, spring-boot

Here is my html code to display the data [image]

I tried displaying data using angularjs

[image]

But it doesn't show select options

[image]

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please do not show code as image, can you copy/paste to make a [mre] ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use models, for that json.
In fact, according to the image code, the `listSubCategory` is missing to have that list of `SubCategory`:

```
Example:
//product
export class Product {
    productName: string = '';
    color: string = '';
    //...
    listSubCategory: SubCategory[] = [];
}

//subCategory.ts
export class SubCategory {
    id: string = '';
    subCategoryName: string = '';
}
//ts
selectedSubCategory = new SubCategory();

//Here it depends on what you want to show.
selectedSubCategory.subCategoryName = 'Select ...';

//html
<select class="form-select" [(ngModel)]="selectedSubCategory">
    <option *ngFor="let subcategory of product.listSubCategory" 
[ngValue]="subcategory">{{subcategory.subCategoryName}}
    </option>
</select>

//selectedSubCategory is going to have your option selected, remember to add 
//controls.
```